# How to fix the "System cannot find the file specified" exception when using BCP

Tags: c#, bcp

I am trying to do a bulk copy using BCP via my C# application. This is the command I need to execute:

`var bcpArgs = "EXEC spReportExecutor @Query = 'SELECT * FROM ExpAifaBrosureCommTape', @Parameters = '<Parameters>  <DBToUse>sql_converted_absaDR</DBToUse></Parameters>'" queryout "C:\MISAutomationReports\BCP\AifaBrosureCommissionTape.dat" -e"C:\MISAutomationReports\BCP\AifaBrosureCommissionError.txt" -T -c -S [myserver] -d [mydatabase]`

And I execute the command as follows: 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("bcp.exe", bcpArgs);`

This works fine on my local machine, but when deployed to our dev/prod servers, I get a "The system cannot find the file specified" exception. However, if I run the bcpArgs directly in commandline, the process is successful.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the path of `bcp.exe`, instead of:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("bcp.exe", bcpArgs)
```

try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path\bcp.exe", bcpArgs)
```

Comment: And just as you answered it I did exactly that! But why would it work on my local machine (without specifying the bcp path)?

Comment: I believe because the c# application and the bcp tool are residing on the same folder on your local machine